# How to add more functionality to the drop down menus in gnome ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, appmenu, 15.10

When I click on an open program in the activities bar of gnome all I receive is the option to quit the program, is there any way for this drop down menu to show more actions. For example when I am using Nautilus by clicking on the drop down I recieve the following options

> New Window
>
> Sidebar
>
> Preferences
>
> etc

So what I would like to have is this functionality for other programs, namely I care for having these menus for Google Chrome. So does anyone know how I can add these to gnome 3.16?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for "nautilus extensions". Nautilus is the real name of the file manager used in both Unity and gnome-shell desktops.

You can write extensions:

1. [as scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14700/how-can-i-write-nautilus-scripts-in-python) (although I think this is sort-of-deprecated)
2. In [C using the `gtk` libraries](http://www.hvoigt.net/dev/nautilus-extensions-tutor.html)
3. or in [various mixed languages](https://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/extending-nautilus-context-menus-using-nautilus-actions-scripts-and-python-extensions/)

However, for personal experience, expect to find a lot of outdated documentation and a lack of clear, up-to-date documentation around. Probably the best way to get started is to try to dig at the sources of available extensions:

```
[romano:~] % wajig search nautilus | grep extens
libnautilus-extension-dev - libraries for nautilus components - development version
libnautilus-extension1a - libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
nautilus-share - Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
nautilus-actions - nautilus extension to configure programs to launch
nautilus-compare - Context menu comparison extension for Nautilus file manager
nautilus-filename-repairer - Nautilus extension for filename encoding repair
nautilus-gtkhash - nautilus extension for computing checksums and more using gtkhash
nautilus-image-converter - nautilus extension to mass resize or rotate images
nautilus-pastebin - Nautilus extension to send files to a pastebin
nautilus-wipe - Secure deletion extension for Nautilus
rabbitvcs-nautilus - Nautilus extension for RabbitVCS
tortoisehg-nautilus - Graphical tool for working with Mercurial (Nautilus extension)
clamtk-nautilus - Nautilus MenuProvider extension for clamtk
nautilus-pushbullet - An extension for Nautilus to send files with pushbullet
```

..and more, like `nautilus-script-manager`, `nautilus-scripts-manager` (yes they're different!), or `nautilus-image-manipulator` and `nautilus-open-terminal`.